# How to check if a particular value exists in a variable which stores multiple value in mysql?

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create an sql trigger statement using phpmyadmin trigger interface.

Trying to do something for table 1 as shown below :

```
BEGIN

declare @valid_number int ;

select id into @valid_number from table 2 ;

if 10 does not exist in @valid_number then
{do something here}
end if;
END
```

how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: a variable in a stored routine can't store multiple values, just a single one. Your statement

```
select id into @valid_number from table 2 ;
```

will only work, if the query returns exactly one row. An error will occur, if the query returns multiple rows, a warning, if the query returns no row at all, see the manual page to [SELECT ... INTO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html):

> The INTO clause can name a list of one or more variables, which can be
>   user-defined variables, stored procedure or function parameters, or
>   stored program local variables. [...]
>
> The selected values are assigned to the variables. The number of
>   variables must match the number of columns. The query should return a
>   single row. If the query returns no rows, a warning with error code
>   1329 occurs (No data), and the variable values remain unchanged. **If
>   the query returns multiple rows, error 1172 occurs** (Result consisted
>   of more than one row).

**Solution:**

It's not difficult to create a statement that gives you the desired answer in exact one row, i.e.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) into valid_number FROM example WHERE id = 10;
```

This query will return 0, if the id 10 does not exists in column id and the count of occurences else. Of course there are several ways to achieve this, this is just one of them. You could rewrite your stored routine to:

```
BEGIN
    -- prefer local variables, don't use user defined, if not needed.
    DECLARE valid_number int;

    SELECT COUNT(*) into valid_number FROM example WHERE id = 10;

    IF valid_number = 0 THEN 
        -- do something here 
    END IF;

    SELECT result;
END
```

**Note**

You could use a [cursor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cursors.html) to traverse the result of a query, but most times one wants to avoid a cursor. To use a cursor under similar conditions as of this question would not be the SQL way to do it and most times very inefficient.

Comment: Thank you, that is the exact soluting i was looking for, i didn't think of count(*) before and noone even mentioned it and just kept downvoting it. It solves the problem as of now , but what happens if i actually need to fetch results from other table to execute them each?